# command or code to run two processes in the same time (parallel)

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have two processes:

The first process, I run with: . / Vlc video >> resu.txt   it gives me an output file resu.txt

The second process is a script that makes calculations on the file resu.txt
The name of this script is calcule.sh, I run it with: . / Calcul.sh

I want to run two processes at the same time. ie having two parallel processes.

how I could run two processes in parallel (. / Vlc video >> resu.txt and  . / Calcul.s ). Is there a command that do this ? Please,  can you propose me a code that will do that

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Do you want to "pipe" your 2 process ? i.e. the output of the first becaming the input of the second ?

Answer (score 5):

Modify `calcule.sh` so that it reads from standard input rather than from `resu.txt`, then execute your commands in a pipe, as in

```
. /Vlc video | ./calcule.sh
```

Comment: My script Calcule.sh  has the following form

while read qp
do

instructions
done <resu.txt


how I could change it to read from the standard input?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real parallel processing here. Your second script can't run until it has some data to process which is produced by the first script.
This is simply a case for [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29). You don't need to use a temporary file to store the result, just pipe the first one's output to the second's input:

```
./Vlc video | ./Calcul.s
```

You have to slightly change your 2nd script for this so as to read from the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If the processes depend on each other, i.e. process 1 (VLC) must finish and generate its output in order for process 2 (your script) to have something to work with, then they are sequential and cannot be run in parallel due to the data dependency.

Answer (score 0):

if no data dependency and can be run in parallel then use these two commands

```
./ Vlc video > resu.txt &
```

and then

```
./calculate.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the "resu" file AND send the text to the other script, use [`tee`](http://man.cx/tee)

```
./Vlc video | tee resu.txt | ./calculate.sh
```